# Can heap sort be used to sort a list in descending order?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to use heap sort to sort an array into descending order but I ran into some problems. Here is my current code:

```py
def heap(list):
    for i in range(len(list)//2-1, len(list)):
        heapify(list, i, len(list))
    for i in range(0, len(list)-1):
        list[i], list[0] = list[0], list[i]
        heapify(list, 0, i)
def heapify(list, i, n):
    left = len(list) - (2*i+1)
    right = len(list)-(2*i+2)
    print(left, right)
    largest = i
    if left < n and list[left] > list[largest]:
        largest = left
    if right < n and list[right] > list[largest]:
        largest = right
    if largest != i:
        list[i], list[largest] = list[largest], list[i]
        heapify(list, largest, n)
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong. Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What problems did you run into? What does your data look like? How are you calling *heap()* ? Also, top tip, don't shadow built-ins - e.g., don't call a list *list*

Answer (score 0):

You could just implement a traditional heap sort and allow for a *reverse* parameter (just like the built-in sort functionality). Then test for it and use a reversing slice if required.

Note that this implementation sorts *in situ*

```
import random

def heapify(lst, n, i):
    m = k if (k := 2 * i + 1) < n and lst[i] < lst[k] else i

    if (k := k + 1) < n and lst[m] < lst[k]:
        m = k

    if m != i:
        lst[i], lst[m] = lst[m], lst[i]
        heapify(lst, n, m)


def heap(lst, reverse=False):
    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(n//2, -1, -1):
        heapify(lst, n, i)

    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        lst[i], lst[0] = lst[0], lst[i]
        heapify(lst, i, 0)
    if reverse:
        lst[:] = lst[::-1]


a = [random.randint(1, 10_000) for _ in range(1_000)]
b = a[::]
heap(a)
assert a == sorted(b)
a = [random.randint(1, 10_000) for _ in range(1_000)]
b = a[::]
heap(a, reverse=True)
assert a == sorted(b, reverse=True)
```

**Note:**

This is interesting as a pure programming exercise but should not be used to replace Python's built-in (and very efficient) sorting functionality